# Dynamic method return type in C#

Tags: c#, methods, dynamic, types

I need your help. I've got the following situation that I have a method with has to determine some conditions and depending on these conditions, returning an object of a specific type.

Now, I do not want to say `public object methodXY()` with `object` as return type but I have the approach which does not seem to work yet.

```
public T methodXY<T>()
{
if (condition A)
   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(myValue, typeof(myType));
else if (condition B)
   return (T)Convert.ChangeType(myValue, typeof(myOtherType));
else
   throw new exception("xyz")
}
```

But with this, it seems that I have to set the return type already when calling the method. That's what I don't want and don't can.

```
//myType looks like this
public class myType 
{
public string name;
public string firstname;
public string address;
}
```

and

```
//myOtherType looks like
public class myOtherType
{
public string name;
public string firstname;
}
```

Do you need more or more detailed information? Let me know.

Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT:**

Here is the complete code sample of the method with `object`

```
public object myMethod(MyDto myDto)
    {
        userHasRoles = GetUserRoles();

        if (userHasRoles .Contains("Admin"))
            return (mapper.Map<myType>(myDto));
        else if (userHasRoles.Contains("User"))
            return (mapper.Map<myOtherType>(myDto));

        throw new Exception("No elements!");
    }
```

Comment: Do all the returntypes implement the same interface?

Comment: There are a few rare cases where this is necessary. Can you tell us what the method actually does so we are sure that there is no better way (to maintain type safety)?

Comment: @AlexS no they don't. They are actually two different objects. I've edited my question so you can see the difference.

Comment: @Sweeper the method does determine which roles the user has and depending on that it returns a different `List<myType>` or `List<myOtherType>`

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile-time then it is impossible to do this in a statically-typed language.

Comment: @RaphaelM. - The code `condition A` and `condition B` does not compile. Any chance you could give us a [mcve] of the code but with a `public object methodXY()` signature so that we can see what you're trying to do? I want real, runable code.

Comment: I see, how do you want to use the return value of the method. Let's say if I write `var value = methodXY()` what would the type of `value` be? `List<myType>` or `List<myOtherType>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity see edit:)

Comment: @Sweeper If the user is Admin then `List<myType>` if he is User then `List<myOtherType>`

Comment: @RaphaelM. - Thanks for the code. You do know that there's a special hell for people who write `throw new Exception("Some Message")`? You should only ever raise a (1) specific exception when your code  (2) cannot recover from some situation. Your code doesn't meet either of those conditions. Have a read of [Eric Lippert's Vexing Exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/).

Comment: Actually, what you want is like 'asking for a hamburger after you ordered a hot dog.' It is impossible to change the return type after you kick start the function.

Comment: @RaphaelM. - Now, to more directly address your question, it seems like `myMethod` is trying to return one of two different "user" objects. Can they not share a common type or interface? Or is the real-world `myMethod` doing more than this? If so, what is its design purpose?

Comment: @Enigmativity Its purpose is to get the users roles, create the request for the Dtos and give them back to the controller

Comment: @RaphaelM. - Then they should return a common type. After you receive the object back you can do `if (instance is Manager manager) { /* do stuff with manager */ }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the problem, you need to return a more complete data when the retriever is the admin, and a not-so-complete one when not.

If that is the objective, then you can retrieve the appropriate data from the database and fill in an object of one of the following classes:

```
public class PersonData {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
}

public class ExtendedPersonData: PersonData {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
    public string Address { get; private set; }
}
```

Since the latter class inherits from the former, you can just create a `List<PersonData>` and that will cover both cases.

Another, different approach: the data class takes into account the user in order to return or not certain data:

```
class Person {
    public Person(User usr, string address)
    {
        this.User = usr;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public string User { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Surname { get; private set; }
    public string Address {
         get {
             string toret = "N/A";

             if ( this.User.IsAdmin() ) {
                 toret = this.address;
             }

             return toret;
         }
    }

    private string address;
}
```

Neither of both solutions is perfect, and both have their own issues, but the problem, at least how you stated it, cannot be solved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works! Now another problem, my validation fails with the error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Validation.Validators.PersonDataValidator' to type 'FluentValidation.IValidator'1[PersonData]` Any idea?

Comment: It seems you should be creating a class inheriting from `FluentValudation.IValidator<PersonData>`, while you are creating a class from `Validation.Validators.PersonDataValidator`. Apart from that, I cannot help further. I suggest you create another question with some small, self-explanatory code.